# Redirect a url to a different server

Tags: redirect, hosts-file, regular-expressions

I'm looking for a way to redirect any url I visit on my computer (Mac), say `www.example1.com/a/b/[\d]+`, to another url `www.example2.com/a/[\d]+`. I don't want this to be on the IP level, just for that particular URL matched by a regular expression.

/etc/hosts was my first idea, but unsure how to do the regex match to capture the numbers and pass it to the second URL defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in a hosts file as it is purely an IP-to-name mapping. It either needs to be done on the web server, or on a proxy server.

[Apache](http://httpd.apache.org) will allow you do to this with [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) will allow you to do it with [redirectors](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/Redirectors).